# Audio HTML5 autoplay on chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, html5-audio

this is the code for my audio:

```
<audio autoplay >
<source src="sources/audio/pop.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
<source src="sources/audio/pop.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

this is working fine in FF but not on chrome.
if i add the controls then it works on chrome but still with no autoplay and i don't want the controls.

Comment: Have you tried it with `autoplay="autoplay"`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with videos not autoplaying in Chrome. Chrome now blocks autoplay in video and audio elements. The solution was to delay the .play() function by 1 second. For your audio problem just replace all the 'video' in my snippet with 'audio'.

```
// Autoplay videos
var playVideos = function () {
  // Get all elements with the video tag
  var videos = document.getElementsByTagName('video');
  // Loop through the videos
  for (i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
    // Play video
    videos[i].play();
  } 
};

// Define body variable
var body = document.getElementById('body');
// Wait 1 Second to trick out Chrome
setTimeout(function() {
  // execute the playVideo function
  body.addEventListener('onload', playVideos(), false);
}, 1000);
```

PS: You need to give your Body the id 'body' for this snippet to work.

Comment: This no longer works -- getting "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException".